# Javascript Interface Constructor is Calling but the interface method is not getting called in android webview

Tags: android, methods, webview, constructor

Here is the code i used..

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new 
         WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

and Javascript Interface class is

public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{

```
    private Context context;
    WebView webView;

    /*
     * Need a reference to the context in order to sent a post message
     */
    public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("Inside Interface","Hello Vinod Dirishala");
    }

    /*
     * This method can be called from Android. @JavascriptInterface
     * required after SDK version 17.
     */

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendDataToDevice(String usertype,String userid){
        Log.d("Inside SendData2Device","Hello Vinod Dirishala");




    }
}
```

The above WebViewInterface Constructor is calling but the javascript method sendDataToDevice methos is calling which is a javascript method defined in php script like

Android.sendDataToDevice(val1,val2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your source, it works well.
I think the problem might be in your environment.

my steps is;

**1. write html at (app\src\main\assets\test.html)**

```
<html>
<script>
    function echoBack()
    {
            var txtVal1 = document.getElementById("val1").value;
            var txtVal2 = document.getElementById("val2").value;
            Android.sendDataToDevice(txtVal1, txtVal2);
    }
</script>
<body style="padding:10px;">
<br/><br/><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" style="padding:10px;">
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2" style="padding:10px;">
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Send to Android" onclick="echoBack()" style="padding:10px;">
</body>
</html>
```

**2. write activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new
                WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
        setContentView(webview);
    }

    public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{

        private Context context;
        WebView webView;

        /*
         * Need a reference to the context in order to sent a post message
         */
        public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context){
            this.context = context;
            Log.e("Inside Interface","Hello Vinod Dirishala");
        }

        /*
         * This method can be called from Android. @JavascriptInterface
         * required after SDK version 17.
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void sendDataToDevice(String usertype,String userid){
            Log.e("Inside SendData2Device","Hello Vinod Dirishala");
        }
    }
}
```

**3. running log**

```
08-27 16:04:14.436 22459-22459/com.test E/Inside Interface: Hello Vinod Dirishala
08-27 16:04:26.586 22459-22511/com.test E/Inside SendData2Device: Hello Vinod Dirishala
```